# Count of values in an element of a unbounded structure

Tags: xslt-1.0, xquery

I am trying to draft a xquery based on version 1.0 which does count the number of occurance of a value in an element under a unbounded structure.

For example..I am getting below request as input to my systems and I want to count how many time, I got FC words in OutcomeCode element were DataDetail and PerEquipment both are unbounded structure.

looking for your valuable suggestion in it. As per requirement, answer should be 3 as we got 2 FC in first DataDetail  occurrence and 1 in last one.

```
    <v4:DataDetails xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v4="http://services.xx.net/PP/v4">
   <v4:DataDetail>
      <v4:PerEquipment>
         <v4:OutcomeCode>FC</v4:OutcomeCode>
         <v4:OutcomeDescription>FC Data</v4:OutcomeDescription>
      </v4:PerEquipment>
      <v4:PerEquipment>
         <v4:OutcomeCode>FC</v4:OutcomeCode>
         <v4:OutcomeDescription>FC Data</v4:OutcomeDescription>
      </v4:PerEquipment>
      </v4:DataDetail>
   <v4:DataDetail>
       <v4:PerEquipment>
         <v4:OutcomeCode>OG</v4:OutcomeCode>
         <v4:OutcomeDescription>OG Data</v4:OutcomeDescription>
      </v4:PerEquipment>
      <v4:PerEquipment>
         <v4:OutcomeCode>FC</v4:OutcomeCode>
         <v4:OutcomeDescription>FC Data</v4:OutcomeDescription>
      </v4:PerEquipment>
  </v4:DataDetail>
</v4:DataDetailsResponse>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to evaluate the number of occurrences, the following query should suffice:

```
count(//*:OutcomeCode[. = 'FC'])
```

Please note that any 'FC' substring will contribute to the result. If you want to count words, you can use the 'contains text' keywords of XQuery Full Text instead (provided that your XQuery processor provides support for it):

```
count(//*:OutcomeCode[. contains text 'FC'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, this query does not exact does what is needed here. I am looking for count of FC which is under the OutcomeCode code. The above wild card search will scan through the payload and will give how many FC we have.

Comment: Is there a way, I can drill down to specific column and check for FC word.. however, we need to keep in mind that DataDetail and PerEquipment are unbounded structure.. so they may also count N times

Comment: Sorry, you are obviously right. What about `count(//*:OutcomeCode[. = 'FC'])` ?

Comment: I have updated my answer (assuming that the new query matches your requirements).

Comment: thanks for your help. definitely your answer helped me a lot and its working as expected.